# Generate a sublist in prolog given first element and length

Tags: list, prolog

Given the start position and length, I want to generate a sublist of that length. I did it below using an accumulator:

```
get_sublist(_,_,0,Sublist,Sublist):-!.
get_sublist(List,Position,Length,Sublist,Acc):-
    nth1(Position,List,Element),
    append([Element],Acc,Acc1),
    Position1 is Position + 1,
    Length1 is Length - 1,
    get_sublist(List,Position1,Length1,Sublist,Acc1).
```

Is there a shorter/faster way to do this either by using more built in predicates or using an alternative method? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for:

```
sublist(List, Offset, Length, Sublist):-
  length(Prefix, Offset),
  append(Prefix, Rest, List),
  length(Sublist, Length),
  append(Sublist, _, Rest).
```

Example of use:

```
?- sublist([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k], 3, 6, X).
X = [d, e, f, g, h, i].
```

Notice I'm using count-by-0 for the `Offset` argument here.

Answer (score 0):

if I run your code, I get

```
?- get_sublist([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k], 3, 6, X, []).
X = [h, g, f, e, d, c].
```

then, a reverse/2 is missing ? In case, I would propose the good old findall/3:

```
get_sublist(List,Position,Length,Sublist):-
    Stop is Position+Length-1,
    findall(X, (between(Position,Stop,P),nth1(P,List,X)), Sublist).
```

*edit* bagof/3, by means of *declaration* of scoped variables (just P here), will avoid problems introduced by findall:

```
get_sublist(List,Position,Length,Sublist):-
    Stop is Position+Length-1,
    bagof(X, P^(between(Position,Stop,P),nth1(P,List,X)), Sublist).

?- get_sublist([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K], 3, 6, X).
X = [C, D, E, F, G, H].
```

Comment: I don't need a reverse because after I generate the sublist I will only be using all_different(Sublist). My first try used findall but that caused a variable copying problem when I ran my CLP program.